# Should I use additive probability or multiplicative probability in below scenario

Tags: probability, statistics

I had discussion with my friend(Person A) who is applying for one job assuming he will get interview call as it is through reference
Person A is applying for one job -Probabilty of he getting Job Offer is $\frac12$.(either he gets or don't get)
Me(Person B ) is applying to $5$ jobs each probability of getting each job Offer is $\frac12$ for every interview he attends.
I know these events are independent all can occur at same time.
How do I explain that probability of person B getting job offer is $\frac12*\frac12*\frac12*\frac12*\frac12= \frac{1}{32}$
 which is actually less than probability of person A getting job.Or am I completely wrong will this be a case of additive probability. can some one please explain me

Comment: This is not clear at all.  Can you edit?  If $B$ is applying to five jobs and has, independently, a $\frac 12$ chance of each then $\frac 1{32}$ is the probability of getting (or failing to get)  all $5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability that person A gets a job is $\frac{1}{2}$

The probability that person B gets a job is 1-P[B is rejected from ALL 5 jobs]

Hence the probability that person B gets a job is $1-(\frac{1}{2})^{5}=\frac{31}{32}$